# how to add objects to array in firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the below code which at first run creates a new collection with a document ID that is equal to my UID. This newly created document has an array named 'array' which contains the  cocktailInformation object. So far all works fine.

```
const saveData = (uid) => {
        db
            .collection('users')
            .doc(uid)
            .set({
                array: [ cocktailInformation ]
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log('Document successfully written!');
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error('Error writing document: ', error);
            });
    };
```

the issue arises when i want to add more objects to this array in this document. I checked firestore docs on how to do this and it shows the below

```
var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});

// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("east_coast")
});
```

but i don't know how to integrate this as the current code only updates the current object with the one i send off to firestore. Can anyone give me some tips? BTW this is a react app

Comment: How exactly do you define `db` in your code?

Comment: hey @DougStevenson I got this fixed thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61460221/12998811

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update the document by doing the following:

```
db.collection('users').doc(uid).update({
    array: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("value")
});
```

Comment: Tried this mate. It gives me a Cannot read property 'arrayUnion' of undefined error when run

Comment: where are u calling this? in the browser or cloud functions?

Comment: I am calling this in the react component from which I want to add the new data to the array

Comment: also which version of firestore are u using?

Comment: I added the version and some other info you might find relevant to the issue here mate- https://www.codepile.net/pile/qDpgNnEV

Comment: in the component try fire.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("value")